# Movie or TV show that involves a mutagenic substance, similar to the Forced Evolutionary Virus dipping vats from the first Fallout game

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This could have been a movie or TV show, but I believe it was in colour.

There was a villain who had given himself a reptilian tail and menaces the heroes in some sort of facility with walkways above a substance that causes whatever is submerged in it to mutate instantly.

A very specific example: if one were to dip their finger in it, that finger alone would mutate.

I remember there being a lady with a gun, who's disarmed by the villain via a tail spin.
The part I remember vividly was a young boy trying to escape by monkey-barring it above the substance, but his feet get submerged and when he pulled them out he had disturbing, monster/reptilian/mutant feet.

The substance isn't an injection, consumable contaminated food; in fact the closest thing I've found to this substance in media is the green goo from the *Doctor Who* episode, "The Ark in Space." It looked similar to the 'dipping' cinematic in the first *Fallout* game, but again only affects what's been submerged.

I've been searching fruitlessly for this and would appreciate the help, as it's been four years of researching and absolutely zero success or leads.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Was this a cartoon or live-action?

Comment: In roughly which year did you first watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Definately live action, and the year was potentially between 1997-2000